# Rspec errors following Hartl's rails guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have been following the guide for a while now and unfortunately have been stuck getting these tests to pass. Thank you for your time because I have given up looking for what is wrong and am desperate for any help.

```
Failures:

1) signup with valid information after saving user 
 Failure/Error: it {should have_link('Sign out')}
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) signup with valid information after saving user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:96:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) signup with valid information after saving user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
   expected css "title" with text "Example User" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) create user page 
 Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('h1', text: 'Creating New User')}
   expected css "h1" with text "Creating New User" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) create user page 
 Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign Up')}
   expected css "title" with text "Sign Up" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:132:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
   expected css "title" with text "New Name" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:131:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) edit with invalid info 
 Failure/Error: it {should have_content('error')}
   expected there to be content "error" in "with invalid info"
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:117:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

10) edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
   expected css "h1" with text "Update your profile" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:111:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

11) edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
   expected css "title" with text "Edit user" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:112:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) profile page 
 Failure/Error: it{should have_selector('h2', text: user.name)}
   expected css "h2" with text "Person 66" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) profile page 
 Failure/Error: it{should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}
   expected css "title" with text "Person 67" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My User Pages Spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do
subject {page}

describe "index" do
  before do
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
    visit users_path
  end

 it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
 it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All Users') }

  describe "pagination" do
    before(:all) {30.times {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}}
    after(:all) {User.delete_all}

  it {should have_selector('div.pagination')}

  describe "delete links" do

    it { should_not have_link('delete') }

    describe "as an admin user" do
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
      before do
        sign_in admin
        visit users_path
      end

      it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
      it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
    end
    end
  end

  it "should list each user" do
  User.all.each do |user|
    page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
     end
    end

  end
end

 describe "create user page" do
 before {visit new_user_path}

    it {should have_selector('h1', text: 'Creating New User')}
    it {should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign Up')}
end

describe "profile page" do
 let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
 before {visit user_path(user)}
    it{should have_selector('h2', text: user.name)}
    it{should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}    
end 

describe "signup" do
  before { visit new_user_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
   before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    choose("user_admin_true")
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
   end

   it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)  
   end

   describe "after saving user" do
    before {click_button submit}
    let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }        
    it { should have_link('Sign out')}
  end

end
end

describe "edit" do
 let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
  end

 describe "page" do
  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
 end

 describe "with invalid info" do
  before {click_button "Save changes"}
  it {should have_content('error')}
 end

 describe "with valid information" do
  let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
  let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
  before do
    fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
    fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
    fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Save changes"
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
  specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
end
end
```

Users Controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Account creation succesful. Welcome to the CeFam Online Database"    
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
     end 
  end

 def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User removed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def signed_in_user
    flash[:notice] = "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    redirect_to signin_url unless signed_in?
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end
```

Header

```
 <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "Image Home Logo", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>

            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>

              <!--Visibile only when signed in-->
              <% if signed_in? %>

              <li><%= link_to "List users", users_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Search", '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Add Entry", '#' %></li>

              <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>

              <%else%>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
              <%end%>
            </ul>


          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

User's show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title,@user.name) %>
<h1> User Profile </h1>
<h2><%=@user.name%><br>
<%= @user.email %><br>
Administrator: <%= @user.admin%>
</h2>
```

User's new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title,'Sign Up')%>

<h1>Creating New User</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4 offset4">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :admin %>

      <%= f.radio_button :admin, "true"%> Yes <br>
      <%= f.radio_button :admin, "false"%> No<br><br>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      <br>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source of at least one of your problems, look at your `user_pages_spec.rb`:

```
it "should list each user" do
  User.all.each do |user|
    page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
  end
end
```

You want to test for `User.paginate` not `User.all` (because Capybara has no way of seeing past the default 30 rendered on a single paginated view). It's explained in the tutorial that testing for one page should suffice since the `will_paginate` gem is pretty well-tested already.

So replace that block with this, and your pagination tests should pass:

```
it 'should list each user' do
  User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
    page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
  end
end
```